# Resource Handling approach in Maven

Tags: java, maven

I am handling below way to work with files.

1. 1st Approach:
   I am keeping my files in D:\Projects\JavaProjects\LearnCucumber\src\test\resources\
   -With the help of ClassLoader, I am getting the path and working on files

`ResourceUtils.class.getClassLoader().getResource(".").getPath();`

2. 2nd Approach:
   Now, I keep file in D:\Projects\JavaProjects\LearnCucumber\BrowserDrivers\
   using `System.getProperty("user.dir")` I am dealing with files in this approach.

Now Which approach is efficient, when we run our code in different platform(windows,linux) in terms of handling files. Does it really makes difference?

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid working with files on the filesystem as those are usually less portable from one operating system to the next one. Also if you put files at certain locations other users of your software need to have those files available at the same location as well, whereas with your approach #1 you can ship these files directly with your application (packaged as jar) and access it from the classpath easily.